# Is it ok to supply power from one device a use Common on another?

Tags: hvac, common-wire

I have a valve relay with R and W going to a stat, and there’s a spare wire I want to connect to a C wire. The relay doesn’t have a Common and I need the common for a wifi stat. I have a separate zone panel independent of the relay valve which has an unused Common terminal. Can I wire the third stat wire to it and leave R and H connected to the valve? Would this setup work with R and C in different places,

Comment: No, that's not going to work. They don't have anything in ... ... common :).  Just change to a different/better Aube relay that exposes common.  Aube is well aware of the demand for it and has responded with products.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not going to work.

It is not a close loop circuit.

You need the C from same transformer where the R comes from.